# Vagrant: specify the disk size for the VMware provider

Tags: vmware, vagrant

I'm trying to resize the disk of my vagrant box but without success.
I have seen the plugin vagrant-disksize but he is only available for Virtualbox while I use VMware.

How can I expand the disk?

I have tested with the Vagrant disks Experimental Feature but the following error appears:

> Failed to expand the disk 'D:/Vagrant/vagrant_vmware/.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_desktop/136192e3-2e68-46e1-9bdf-2740af3059af/Rocky-8-Vagrant-VMware-8.7-20221121.0.x86_64-cl1.vmdk': The called function cannot be performed on partial chains. Open the parent virtual disk

You can find below my vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'rockylinux/8'
  config.vm.network 'private_network'

  config.vm.disk :disk, size: "15GB", primary: true
  
  config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |v|
    v.gui = true
    v.vmx["memsize"] = "2048"
    v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "4"
  end
end
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here, this topics provides you some tips about how setup size of main disks: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/13230. it seems you cannot reduce size below default threshold: 128 GB.